# How to login my ios app via Facebook App?

Tags: ios

When I use Facebook SDK to login my ios app, it always present me the Web login, rather than Switching the Facebook App???  I have done all as follow as the Facebook Documents, what should i do?

Comment: you can find reason here http://stackoverflow.com/a/31311184/5362916

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Facebook Login Tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555034/ios-facebook-login-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311125/how-to-integrate-facebook-without-redirect-safari-browser-in-ios-app-with-latest).

And try,

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
login.loginBehavior=FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
```

Comment: The facebook documents says "The FBSDKLoginBehavior enum specifies which log-in methods may be used. The SDK
  will determine the best behavior based on the current device (such as iOS version)."

So, I think the reason I cannot login my app by Facebook App is that the facebook sdk decide it!

Thank you!